# String comparison not working correctly

Tags: java, string, comparison, equals

I'm having a problem with String comparison, while some words return the correct result others simply don't..

```
for (int s = 0; s < subjects.getLength(); s++) {
    Element subject = (Element) subjects.item(s);
    String sub = subject
                    .getElementsByTagName("name").item(0)
                    .getTextContent();
    Log.d("Subject", getSubject() + "!A");
    Log.d("Subject", sub + "!B");
    Log.d("Subject", "equalsIC: " + String.valueOf(getSubject().equalsIgnoreCase(sub)));
    Log.d("Subject", "Contains: " + String.valueOf(getSubject().contains(sub)));
    Log.d("Subject", "Equals: " + String.valueOf(getSubject().equals(sub)));
    Log.d("Subject", "ContentEqu: " + String.valueOf(getSubject().contentEquals(sub)));
    Log.d("Subject", "Length A: " + String.valueOf(getSubject().length()) + "; Length B: " + String.valueOf(sub.length()));
    if (getSubject().equalsIgnoreCase(subject
               .getElementsByTagName("name").item(0)
               .getTextContent())) {
        Log.d("Subject", getSubject() + "Success !C");
```

The getSubject method is returning a String.
While this works perfect for "BK G3":

```
D/Subject﹕ BK G3!A
D/Subject﹕ BK G3!B
D/Subject﹕ equalsIC: true
D/Subject﹕ Contains: true
D/Subject﹕ Equals: true
D/Subject﹕ ContentEqu: true
D/Subject﹕ Length A: 5; Length B: 5
D/Subject﹕ BK G3Success !C
```

It simply fails with "D  G4":

```
D/Subject﹕ D  G4!A
D/Subject﹕ D  G4!B
D/Subject﹕ equalsIC: false
D/Subject﹕ Contains: false
D/Subject﹕ Equals: false
D/Subject﹕ ContentEqu: false
D/Subject﹕ Length A: 5; Length B: 5
```

I tried it with sub.trim(), but nothing changed..

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Debugging gives me the following information:

```
sub = (java.lang.String@83000929)"D  G4"
value = {char[5]@830092913560}
hashCode = 0
offset = 0
count = 5

((Activity_Add)this).subject = java.lang.String@830088265176)"D  G4"
value = {char[59]@830080636976}
hashCode = 0
offset = 6
count = 5
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug each string to see the byte by byte it's content?

Comment: From what I see they are in fact different. Looking at the html from your post I can see that the first string is `D &nbsp;G4` and the second one is `D  G4`.

Comment: What are those 59 chars that the second string have?

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira It's probably due to this line `subject = subjectList.get(position);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`sub.replaceAll("\\s+","")`

instead of

`sub.trim();`